# How to user Mandrill Handlebars in Java?

Tags: email, templates, mandrill

We are using Mandrill to send emails. Till now we used only the templates but now we need to use handlebars. We use this [Java client](https://github.com/rschreijer/lutung) But I was not able to make the handlebars functionality work.

I am sending a message using:

```
MandrillMessageStatus[] statuses = mandrillApi.messages().sendTemplate(key, templateContent, message, false);
```

Where I should add the map of values to be used by the handle bars?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to enable Handle bars on Mandrill and they mention it all the way on the bottom of the docs. So if you are the type of people that skim and then get their hands dirty... then just to the bottom part of [this](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content) to learn how to enable it